# Convert Syntax from cURL to php cURL

Tags: php, excel, curl, jira

I have a cURL command which works very well en CLI (via git Bash). See below:

```
curl -D- -k -o tvdata.xls -u adminid:adminpw -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" https://localhost/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?jqlQuery=project+%3D+LPCCU+AND+type+%3D+Incident
```

This command export very well all issues in an excel file (xls) from my JIRA.
Now i want to transform this command to php curl. I have tried this code below:

```
    $url = 'https://build.bnum.laposte.fr/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?jqlQuery=project+%3D+LPCCU+AND+type+%3D+Incident';

    $username ='adminid';
    $password ='adminpw';

    $file = fopen('tvdata.xls', 'w');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/vnd.ms-excel")); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    fclose($file);
```

but when i run this php code, he create an **empty** excel file only, but without to get an error. If somebody can figure out this problem please?

Thanks in advance

Achillix

Comment: Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to 1

Comment: @diavolic THX for your answer, but no changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using on-line converters like [this](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/) one?

From...

```
curl -D- -k -o tvdata.xls -u adminid:adminpw -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" https://localhost/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?jqlQuery=project+%3D+LPCCU+AND+type+%3D+Incident
```

...you get:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://localhost/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?jqlQuery=project+%3D+LPCCU+AND+type+%3D+Incident");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "adminid" . ":" . "adminpw");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

...compared with your sample code, CURLOPT_URL and CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER are different, and some other options are not set.

Comment: thx for your response and your help. The converter is awesome! i tried your code and now i get an error message:
error ssl certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain 
in cURL it is the option -k to evate the SSL problem. any idea? THX in advance

Comment: I have added this 2 options and it works:    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   But you solved my problem in 99%. So  Thank you very much. cheers